# Silence Deprecation Warnings in Yarn

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I'm getting some warnings when I run yarn watch command.

```
Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

They are thrown by my node_modules folder so I can't change them. Is there a way to suppress them when I run yarn watch command? I've found some information about yarnrc but nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

dart-sass has deprecated / in favor of math.div. Compiling https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss now results with many sass warnings.

try to update,
UPDATE: Solved by manually downgrading sass to 1.32.*

Comment: I know that, I said it is in node_modules files and I wanted to suppress them. Not change my package version because I need them.